# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

---

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in N:\home\localhost\www\phpsite\testreg.php on line 36

Как сделать, чтобы не выдавало ошибку?

Comment: @Luchfan1, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не выдавало - @ перед функцией.
Чтобы **избежать** ошибки, пишите так:

```
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT `col` FROM `oshibka` WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
$myrow = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
  $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Еще лучше

```
try{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `col` FROM `oshibka` WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
}catch(Exception e){
//Обработка ошибок
}
```

Comment: тут можно поспорить что лучше. здесь была большая тема про эксэпшны

Comment: эксепшены накладные, да. Но они чище. =) Впрочем, смотря для чего нужен этот кусок кода. Если для отображения или неотображения малозначимого блока - можно вообще одной собакой обойтись. Если это запрос основного контента, таки лучше эксепшн.

Comment: @knes, ещё лучше - единый handler ошибок

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще проще. Ошибка то скорее всего в запросе и мы её просто не видим, а лучше её вывести и посмотреть!

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) || die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
if ($result) {
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

И всё..

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно вкурил, то запрос пришёл пустой и ты его в другую функцию кидаешь.
Надо сделать заглушку, что бы такого не происходило. Я это делаю так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'",$db) or die('Cann`t query '.mysql_error);
```

Ошибка происходит из-за не совпадения типов: функция принимает тип данных resource, твой запрос пришёл пустым, что приравнивается к FALSE (boolean).

Comment: or die// Не надо учить людей плохому :) Не всегда ошибка БД должна рушить систему. Хорошая система должна справляться с такими мелочами.